# Json Deserializer Returning NUll

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, system.text.json

Hello I am trying to deserialize a json file. A sample of it is below from the start to the first element:

```
 {
  "spell": [
    {
      "name": "Affect Normal Fires",
      "school": "Al",
      "verbal": "1",
      "somatic": "1",
      "material": "0",
      "materials": "",
      "range": "5 yds./level",
      "aoe": "10 foot-radius",
      "castingTime": "1",
      "duration": "2 rds./level",
      "save": "None",
      "damage": "",
      "description": "...",
      "level": "1",
      "caster": "Wizard",
      "source": "Players Hand Book page 170",
      "sphere": [],
      "subschools": [ "Elemental Fire", "Alchemy" ]
    },...
```

I created the class structure for it below:

```
   public class Spells
   {
       public List<Spell> list_of_spells { get; set;}
   }

   public class Spell 
   {
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string school { get; set;}
       public string verbal { get; set;} 
       public string somatic { get; set;}
       public string material { get; set;}
       public string materials { get; set;}
       public string range { get; set;} 
       public string aoe { get; set;}
       public string castingTime { get; set;}
       public string duration { get; set;}
       public string save { get; set;}
       public string damage { get; set;}
       public string description { get; set;}
       public string level { get; set;}
       public string caster { get; set;}
       public string source { get; set;}
       public List<string> sphere { get; set;}
       public List<string> subschools { get; set; }
   }
```

Now When I try to Deserialize it by doing this

```
Spells loadedSpells;
loadedSpells = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Spells>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\spellsv2.json"));
```

loadedSpells.list_of_spells just equals Null

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @PoulBak thanks for the advice I just changed the file so its spells not spell. obviously this doesn't fix the list of spells equals Null issue though, but makes the formatting of the json better

Comment: In your json, your root json object posesses a property "spell". You deserialize it into an instance of the type `Spells`. Please point me at the property of the same name in in your model class `Spells`...

Comment: ` public class Spells   { public List<Spell> list_of_spells { get; set; } `  
I have never worked with JSON file before so I believe "spell" is a list of spells. so I created a public class Spells with
`public List<Spell> list_of_spells { get; set;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your property in the `spells` `class` must be the same name as the root object in the `json` file in order to be correctly mapped to it.

try changing :

```
public class Spells
{
   public List<Spell> list_of_spells { get; set;}
}
```

to :

```
public class Spells
{
   public List<Spell> spell { get; set; }
}
```

[How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Answer (score 2):

fix the class

```
   public class Spells
   {
       public List<Spell> spell { get; set;}
   }

Spells loadedSpells = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Spells>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\spellsv2.json"));
```

or you can keep your property name

```
public class Spells
   {   
       [JsonPeropertyName("spell")]
       public List<Spell> list_of_spells { get; set;}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Serge! I didnt know the name of the variable actually effected the json deserializer!